# DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input

Tags: c#, linq

I've a big problem with my linq query

```
            var t = from tl in _GxEntities.T_L
                             join td in _GxEntities.T_D on (int)tl.fld_rdRequestfk equals td.fld_rqID_pk
                             join tpd in _GxEntities.T_P_D on (int)td.fld_rqID_pk equals tpd.fld_pdRequest_fk                                 
                             where tpd.fld_pdda == null
                                && tpd.fld_pdSU_fk == tl.fld_rdSU_fk
                                && td.fld_rqstatus != 1
                                && tl.fld_rcid != null
                                && tl.loc_id == UsrProfilService.loc_id
                                && tl.fld_rcid.Any(x=> tblRvGxFr.Select(c=>c.Nte).Contains(x.ToString()))
                             group tl by new
                             {
                                 tl.fld_rcid,
                                 tl.fld_rdSU_fk,
                                 tl.fld_rdtRequested_Q,
                                 tl.loc_id
                             } into q
                             select new RVSyntheseDetailModel()
                             {
                                 RC_ID = q.Key.fld_rcid,
                                 SU = (int)q.Key.fld_rdSU_fk,
                                 Ts = (int)q.Sum(k => k.fld_rdtRequested_Q),
                                 LOC_ID = (short)q.Key.loc_id
                             };

        return t.ToList();
```

If I comment `&& tl.fld_rcid.Any(x=> tblRvGxFr.Select(c=>c.Nte).Contains(x.ToString()))` this part I don't have any problem. `tblRvGxFr` is from another entities and looks like this :

```
var dateLimit = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-1);

var tblRtvGrxFr = from tgx in _FtEntities.TL_RV_FR_GX
 where tgx.RV_D_LIM_RET > dateLimit && tgx.RV_N_IDT_DAP != null && tgx.RV_LOC_ID == SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)UsrProfilService.loc_id)
  select new RVSyntheseRrModel()
  {
      Nte = tgx.RV_ETET,
      Tr = tgx.RV_TR,
      Filiere = tgx.RV_T_PRD,
      Lib_art = tgx.RV_L_ART,
      SU = tgx.RV_N_IDT_DAP,
      Qte_demand = (int?)tgx.RT_Q_DEM_RET ?? 0,
      Ord = 0,
      Tcs = 0,
      AfA = 0,
      PrA = 0,
      Exped = 0,
      Loc_Id = tgx.RV_LOC_ID,
      Reason = tgx.RV_REASON
  };
```

Can you help me? Why do I get this error "DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input"?

And if I change this condition to : && tblRvGxFr.Select(i => i.Nte).Contains(tl.fld_rcid) I've this error : Unable to process the type 'GX.ViewModels.RVSyntheseRrModel[]', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.

Comment: What is the **type** of the `fld_rcid` field? Also is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: fld_rcid is a string and this is Linq to Entities

Comment: Ok. What are you trying to achieve? (A) `fld_rcid` contains any `nte`, (B) any `nte` equals `fld_rcid` (C) any `nte` contains `fld_rcid `

Comment: I want to get all the "fld_rcid" which are in "nte"

Comment: (C) Any nte contains fld_rcid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would use something like this

```
&& tblRvGxFr.Any(c => c.Nte.Contains(tl.fld_rcid))
```

However LINQ to Entities does not support queries involving different `DbContext`s. So you need to grab the `Nte`s into a local list/array

```
var nteList = tblRvGxFr.Select(c => c.Nte).ToList();
```

and then use this instead:

```
&& nteList.Any(nte => nte.Contains(tl.fld_rcid))
```

Hope the `Nte` list is not big, because otherwise the SQL query will be quite big and inefficient. But AFAIK no other multi context solution exists.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nte is a big list

Comment: Too bad. Any chance to use one and the same `DbContext`?

Comment: No it's impossible... before that I was using a view but it was too slow to load that's why my boss asked me to code it with linq... now i'm trying to unite all the subqueries and I'm fighting with the limits of Entity Framework :(